# Why ubuntu is missing letters?

Tags: graphics, fonts

I wondered why my ubuntu is missing letters, the internet, when I'm writing a text in the terminal until the installation had a lot of missing letters, already gave reboot muitasa times and nothing happened, someone help me ??? this impossible use ubuntu as well

P.S:my english is bad,sorry,i am a brazillian
PP.SS:i have a notebook with ubuntu and this dont  happens

Comment: There are a number of possible solutions to this problem.  One that worked for me was `sudo apt-get install xfonts-100dpi`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.. 
what helped me was to downgrade kernel to lts-trusty 3.13.0-71-generic which I have been using before. 
It also helped when I disabled anti-alliasing in system settings, but it looked really bad, so I switched it back on. 
Try that and maybe change title font.. that helped me ;)